# NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath returns false when using iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsfilemanager

I have been trying to play a video with `MPMoviePlayerViewController` and it works fine. But before I play it, I want to check if the video I want to play really exists, so I'm using `NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath`, with the path to the file in the iPhone camera roll

My problem comes when checking if it exists. If I check it with this piece of code :

```
// videoImageUri = "/Users/AppName/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/3DAC8D46-3E32-4143-A552-2DB325CB5965/data/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0006.mov"
NSFileManager.defaultManager().fileExistsAtPath(NSURL(fileURLWithPath : videoImageUri).path!)
```

It returns true when used in `Xcode` simulator, but if used with the iPhone, it returns false, even when the file exists. I know it exists because the `MPMoviePlayerViewController` plays it right.

The path I use when using iPhone is

> /var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0150.MP4

Maybe, is there any permission restriction about reading camera roll?

Comment: Check the case of the path - the simulator treats upper and lower case as the same, but iOS (i.e., an iPhone) does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applications are only allowed to access their own directory. Access to other parts is denied, so naturally all queries for files will say they don't exist.

The internal components like media playing have access to other directories also, otherwise you wouldn't be able to play items from the camera roll at all inside applications.

Seems the simulator doesn't enforce the permissions at all.

[More information about filesystem on iOS.](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)